# MEF Generic Imports

Tags: c#, generics, mef

I have the following example code using MEF:

```
public interface IFoo<T> 
{}

public class Foo<T> : IFoo<T> 
{}

[Export(typeof(IFoo<String>))]
public class Foo : Foo<String> 
{}

public class Bar<T>
{
   [Import]
   private readonly IFoo<T> foo;
}

static void Main()
{
   var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
   catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
   var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
   container.ComposeParts();

   var bar = new Bar<String>();
   //bar.foo would be null
}
```

This doesn't seem to work - the `foo` field is `null`. Is this because its type isn't seen by MEF as `IFoo<String>` ?

Comment: In your declaration of class Foo, you've got `Foo<String> : IFoo<String>`. This declares a generic type confusingly named `String`, it doesn't use the actual string class. What you've got is equivalent to `Foo<T> : IFoo<T>`. If you want Foo to not be generic, to always be a `IFoo<System.String>`, you'll need to do `Foo : IFoo<String>`. If you want class Foo to be generic, I'd rename your generic type to `<T>`, to make it less confusing.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error - I over-condensed the problem and missed out a extra declaration. I've re-edited and now Foo<T> implemented IFoo<T>, and Foo implements inherits Foo<String> (and exports IFoo<String>).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

foo is null because you are creating the instance yourself.  You need to have the container create the instance.

Additionally, you will want to check out the [GenericCatalog](http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Generic%20Catalog&referringTitle=Documentation%20%26%20Features) if you plan on working importing/exporting generics.

Comment: Thanks Tom - I realized that I hadn't composed the bar - but got blinded by thinking that it was a problem with the generic rather than my coding mistake.